# If $A$ and $B$ are countable dense subsets of compact metric space $(X, d)$ with infinitely many isometries, is there isometry such that $f(a) \in B$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, isometry

Let $(X, d)$ be a separable and compact metric space with infinitely many isometires. Let $A, B$ be infinitely countable dense subsets of $X$. Is there an isometry $f : X \rightarrow X$ such that $f(a) \in B$, for some $a \in A$?

Isometry is a function $f : X \rightarrow X$ which satisfies $d(f(x), f(y)) = d(x, y), \forall x,y \in X.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no.  Consider the cylinder $\mathbb S^1\times I\subseteq \mathbb R^3$, where $\mathbb S^1$ is the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$, and $I=[0,1]$, with the metric inherited from the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^3$.

Then there are uncountably many isometries (every isometry of the circle extends to one, and one may also compose with reflections through the plane $z=\frac{1}{2}$), but if $A$ is the set of points at rational height and rational angle, and $B$ is the set of points with height and angle in $\sqrt{2}+\mathbb Q$, then $A$ and $B$ are countable and dense, and no isometry will take any point in $A$ to a point in $B$, since all isometries preserve height (or invert height, but in the latter case, rational heights are still sent to rational heights.)

Comment: Thank you for answer, in general im trying to understand more about isometries on compact metric spaces so at the time i come up with some questions like this one. Do you know some article or book where i can find more about properties of isometries on compact spaces?

Comment: @Goki Unfortunately I don't know of a good reference for this topic offhand.  That might be worth asking as a separate question with the "reference request" tag.

Comment: Beautiful answer! +1 :) A similar idea would be the closed unit disc in $\Bbb R^2$, and then $A$ and $B$ the sets of points whose polar coordinates are in $\Bbb Q$ or $\sqrt 2 + \Bbb Q$ resp. PS: I think the cylinder has some more isometries.. eg reflecting through $x = 0$ or $y = 0$.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen [Never mind my just deleted comment]  Good point, fixed now I think.